# Select type class dynamically in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass

I want to serialize and deserialize case classes to JSON, and after deserializing them, based on their subtype, I'd like to handle them differently. Something like this:

```
  sealed trait Salutation
  case class Hello(name: String)
  case class Greetings(name: String)
  case class HeyThere(name: String)

  trait Handler[A] {
    def greet(salutation: A)
  }

  implicit val helloSalutation: Handler[Hello] =
    new Handler[Hello] {
      def greet(salutation: Hello) = println(s"Hello, ${salutation.name}")
    }
  implicit val greetingsSalutation: Handler[Greetings] =
    new Handler[Greetings] {
      def greet(salutation: Greetings) = println("Greetings.")
    }
  implicit val heyThereSalutation: Handler[HeyThere] =
    new Handler[HeyThere] {
      def greet(salutation: HeyThere) = println("Hey there!")
    }

  val action = deserializeSalutationFromJson[Salutation](jsonStringFromSomewhere) 
  // NOTE: _action_ will be of the correct subtype, e.g. Greeting

  /* TODO val handler = select which handler to use based the type of action */

  handler.greet(action)
```

What is a good pattern in Scala for doing this of selection based on a dynamic type from JSON?

Comment: Which JSON lib are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm using Circe but the JSON parsing is not a problem; I get the correct case class deserialized. My question is rather how I then choose the correct handler for that case class.

Comment: Implicit parameters are applied in compilation time. So you can't use them for handling unknown classes in runtime. I think you should use something like partial function that matches against argument type.